# Javascript / PHP, avoiding CSS clashes

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table, row

I have a simple show and hide Javascript:

```
// JS function used in show/hide connectivity details function in LIB
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".connectivityshow").click(function(event){
        var target = event.target.parentElement.nextSibling;
        $(target).toggle('blind');
    });
});
</script>
```

Then in my PHP I have:

```
print '<tr class="connectivityshow">';
```

the table itself has a class of "connectivity_list" The row I wish to show as `class=connectivityshow` and the one I wish to hide has no class.

```
        // Adding more details to the connectivity list, line details (java show and hide)
        //Calculating Router IP Business (+1 from start ip)
        $ip_num = ip2long($ref['start_ip']);
        $start_ip = long2ip($ip_num + 1);
        print '<tr style="display:none">';
        printf('<td colspan="3">Radius Username: %s<br>Radius Password: %s<br>Bandwidth Usage Allowance: %s</td><td colspan = "4">Router IP: %s<br>Start IP: %s<br>IP Block Size: %s</td>',$ref['radius_username'], $ref['radius_pa$
        print '</tr>';
```

I have zebra based CSS, so every other table is a different colour. With this layout, the hide table picks up the 2nd colour from the CSS. I was tempted to make the CSS just use 3 rows instead, but I do have another table without the show and hide feature which relies on the same CSS.

How would you recommend I get past this?

```
  #main-content table.connectivity_list {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}
#main-content table.connectivity_list thead, #main-content table.connectivity_list thead tr, #main-content table.connectivity_list thead th, #main-content table.connectivity_list thead tr th {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}
#main-content table.connectivity_list tbody {
}
#main-content table.connectivity_list tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ddd;
}
#main-content table.connectivity_list tbody tr {
    background: #ccc;
}
*/ #main-content table.connectivity_list td, #main-content table.connectivity_list th {
    padding: 2px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
#main-content table.connectivity_list tfoot td .bulk-actions {
    padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
}
#main-content table.connectivity_list tfoot td .bulk-actions select {
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#main-content table.connectivity_list tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really understood much, but gathering from tids and bits in your question, if you want to hide `tr` which doesn't have a `class`, do as below

```
   if($('table.connectivity_list').find('tr.Class').length == 0)
   {
       //this is tr with no class, hide it
   }
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it that well.

Comment: The show and hide works, it's just it interferes with existing CSS.

Comment: can u explain what `interferes` means?? is it over-writing or not getting implemented??

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to add a class of `static` to the tr with `connectivityshow`. Then, in your JS, change your selector to `$(".connectivityshow:not(.static)")`

That should run the function on any `connectivityshow` click except if it also has the class of `static`

**Edit**

In your php, change the print of the tr to `print '<tr class="connectivityshow static">';`

In your js, change the click event to `$(".connectivityshow:not(.static)").click`

Doing these two things will let you style the `tr`s as needed without adding additional CSS, but it will also not run the click event if the class `static` is on the element.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: Are you suggesting, the css for connectitvyshow doesn't exist. The php looks at the java.

Are you suggesting I add something there?

Comment: Please see answer for an update. I also had a wrong element name mixed in that may have thrown you off, hope this clears things up

Comment: Interesting the whole table has now vanished, I'm guessing I was supposed to change java to 

    //$(".connectivityshow").click(function(event){ (OLD)
    $(".connectivityshow:not(.static)").click(function(event){

EDIT:
$(".connectivityshow:not(.static)").click{

Same result

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by creating new classes within CSS to stop the conflict.

Thanks all.